# Printing to the screen in a .sql file in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a .sql file I am building for an upgrade to my application that alters tables, inserts/updates, etc.

I want to write to the screen after every command finishes.

So, for instance if I have something like:

```
insert into X...
```

I want to see something like,

> **Starting to insert into table X**
>
> **Finished inserting into table X**

Is this possible in PostgreSQL?

<sub>This sounds like it should be a very easy thing to do, however, I cannot find *anywhere* how to do it.</sub>

Comment: For execution by psql, you could add `\echo Starting to insert into table X` , et cetera, to the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to RAISE a NOTICE in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828127/how-to-raise-a-notice-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you're just feeding a big pile of SQL to [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) then you have a couple of options.

You could run `psql` with `--echo-all`:

> `-a` 
> `--echo-all` 
> Print all input lines to standard output as they
> are read. This is more useful for script processing than interactive
> mode. This is equivalent to setting the variable `ECHO` to `all`.

That and the other "echo everything of this type" options (see [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)) are probably too noisy though. If you just want to print things manually, use `\echo`:

> `\echo` **`text`** [ ... ] 
> Prints the arguments to the standard output, separated by one space and followed by a newline. This can be useful to intersperse information in the output of scripts.

So you can say:

```
\echo 'Starting to insert into table X'
-- big pile of inserts go here...
\echo 'Finished inserting into table X'
```

Comment: Just making it clear that to set the variable `ECHO` to `all`, you can **either** add this to your script (typically this is done at the top of the script): `\set ECHO all`, **or** run the script with `psql --echo-all`.

Answer (score 14):

Via [an answer to *How can I run an ad-hoc script in PostgreSQL?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828127/how-can-i-run-an-ad-hoc-script-in-postgresql/18828523#18828523):

```
DO language plpgsql $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Hello, World!';
END
$$;
```

Depending on what you're doing, I'd be worried about doing a bunch of anonymous code blocks. You might consider storing the above as a function, and passing in whatever value you want logged.

Comment: RAISE NOTICE seems to be a time-consuming statement. My function which processes a table of 140K records was taking 25 mins with 10 RAISE NOTICE statements for each record. I removed all the RAISE NOTICE statements, and for the same set of records, it takes 25 seconds now. So beware while using it.

Answer (score 13):

There's probably a better way to do it. But if you need to use vanilla SQL, try this:

```
SELECT NULL AS "Starting to insert into table X";
-- big pile of inserts go here...
SELECT NULL AS "Finished inserting into table X";
```