# How can I run an ad-hoc script in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to run this in PostgreSQL 9.2:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Hello, World!';
```

And the server says:

```
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RAISE"
LINE 1: RAISE NOTICE 'Hello, World!'
            ^
```

Why?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use an anonymous [code block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html):

```
DO language plpgsql $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'hello, world!';
END
$$;
```

[Variables are referenced](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) using `%`:

```
RAISE NOTICE '%', variable_name;
```

Comment: To make it shorter you could remove line breaks and *language plpgsql*

Comment: @ruut In the pg 9.6 version I am using I frequently get errors trying to create functions where I've forgotten to specify the language `ERROR:  no language specified` Maybe it was previously a default?

Answer (score 24):

`raise` is [`PL/pgSQL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) only.

See *[43.9. Errors and Messages](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html)*.

```
create or replace function r(error_message text) returns void as $$
begin
    raise notice '%', error_message;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select r('an error message');
NOTICE:  an error message
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
'
DECLARE


num int;

 BEGIN
IF TG_OP = ''INSERT'' THEN
select count(*) into num from test_table;
IF num >= 1 THEN
RAISE WARNING ''Cannot Insert more than one row'';
RETURN OLD;
END IF;
ELSE
RETURN NEW;
END IF;

END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44130519/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).