# Why do I see error for the following code?

Tags: postgresql

Why do I see the error ?

```
begin insert into math_qage values(20,40);insert into math_qage(30,79); end;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "insert"
LINE 1: begin insert into math_qage values(20,40);

this  is all I'm trying to do:

Insert multiple records at one go  using begin and end o/p a single txid for all...

Also how do i add the raise notice in the following without it being errored out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple errors...

```
begin; -- semicolon here!
    insert into math_qage values(20,40); -- it's ok
    insert into math_qage values(30,79); -- forgot 'values' here!
commit; -- not 'end'
```

And as mentioned above you can do do it in one request even without transaction:

```
insert into math_qage values (20,40), (30,79);
```

Comment: This works thanks! also how do I use raise notice here ? i.e RAISE NOTICE 'transaction id is :%',  TXID_CURRENT();

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828127/how-to-raise-a-notice-in-postgresql) you can find answer about notice. It can be used only inside ```PL/pgSQL``` code block;

Comment: I can't use a pl/pgsql code block unfortunately but have to retrive the transactionid

Comment: is there a way I can do it ?

Comment: Inside transaction you can just ```select txid_current();```. Not sure if it's possible in second method. Postgres gives a new transaction id for every single query outside transactions. You can try use ```returning```, but there will be as many rows in result as you have inserted. Or just combine: start transaction, insert everything in one query, get transaction id, then commit.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably because of `BEGIN .. END` which you can use only in a procedural body like stored procedure or stored function. Remove that begin and end keyword and you can modify your `INSERT` statement like below for multiple rows insertion

```
insert into math_qage values (20,40), (30,79);
```