# How do you output comments in a postgres sql script

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running a large sql script with postgres as follows:

```
psql < scriptname.sql
```

Each sql statement has a comment explaining (using -- syntax) what it does but it isnt output, and its difficult to match up each statement with output. I simply want to output the comments together with the results of the statements

Comment: Possibly: [Printing to screen in .sql file postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383056/printing-to-screen-in-sql-file-postgres)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for the `\echo` command in the [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) reference.

This is `psql` specific though...

Answer (score 2):

Turn echo on with

```
--echo-all
```

then use it with \echo type your text

```
\echo My comment
```